# A better way to conditionally display info in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I find myself frequently writing code like this in the HTML HEAD and other places:

```
<% if @canonical_url %>
  <link rel="canonical" href="<%= @canonical_url %>"/>
<% end %>
```

I then set the variable in the controller if it's appropriate.

Is there any way of writing the equivalent on one line, or maybe a different way of organizing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I came up with this solution.  In the template:

```
<%= show_if('<link rel="canonical" href="$1"/>', @canonical_url) %>
```

And then the helper method:

```
#
# Return the template text if the variable has a value.
#
def show_if(template, variable)
  if variable
    template.gsub('$1', variable)
  else
    ''
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the double answer, SO will only let me post one URL.

Alternatively, your problem might be solved by using [content_for in your views](http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for) where you want to have this content appear in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I'd need a bit more context to determine what it is that you're trying to do.  Given the information that you provide, I would recommend taking a look at the [canonical-url plugin for Rails](http://www.intridea.com/2009/2/13/utilize-canonical-urls-in-your-rails-apps).

Answer (score 0):

```
def if_value(value, &block)
  if value
    concat(capture(value, &block))
  end
end

<% if_value(@canonical_url) do |value| %>
  <link rel="canonical" href="<%= value %>"/>
<% end %>
```